On properties of the Harmonic numbers and a related coupon collector problem
In a coupon collector problem where we aim to collect $n$ coupons, it takes us in expectation $n H(n)$ trials to collect all coupons, and in expectation, $H(n)$ coupons are collected exactly once (one of them being the last coupon to appear).
Let $s(1)=H(n)$ denote the expected singleton coupons in the first iteration of a coupon collector problem (in the next iteration, we remove all singletons and ask how long it took to collect all non-singleton coupons). Recursively, we can define $s$ for all values, namely $s(2)=H[n-s(1)]=H[n-H(n)]$,
then $s(3)=H[n-s(1)-s(2)]$, and in general,
$$s(t)=H[n-\sum_{i=1}^{t-1}s(i)]$$
FIRST QUESTION: I wonder if there is a simple way to write $s(t)$, which is rather large and cumbersome for $t>3$.
Second, let $f(n,m)$ be the expected time that takes to collect $m$ coupons out of $n$ total coupons. It is known that
$$f(n,m)=n[H(n)-H(n-m)]$$
Note that when $m=n$, $f(n,n)=nH(n)$, as desired.
I am interested in the following sum (and for simplicity let $s(0)=0)$:
$$R=\sum_{i=0}^t \frac{H[n-s(i)] f(n,n-i)}{n-s(i)}$$
SECOND, MAIN QUESTION: Is there a nice way to represent this sum so to avoid having the Harmonics all over the place? Does this expression converge to something?
Background: Simulations indicate that for $n=100$, this expression equals $1.74$, whereas for $n=200$ equals $1.71$.
More background: This is an attempt to answer this question. It works well except that the formula $f(n,m)$ needs to be adjusted.
